# Integrating Flickr API into Android Gridview

Tags: android, api, gridview, flickr

I am pretty new to mobile development. I got a gridview to load images from picasso with this tutorial but i cant seem to get my flickr api integrated correctly. Info or point me to a working tutorial would be much appreciated. 
http://javatechig.com/android/download-and-display-image-in-android-gridview#1-addgridview-in-activity-layout

Comment: Maybe this would help: http://grishma102.blogspot.com/2013/12/flickr-api-in-android.html

Comment: Thank you this look great! i will try it out